# How to configure VS Code to remember proxy settings (Windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm a little bit fed up of this window:

[image: VS Code proxy authentication window]

I checked the configuration and I added the proxy URL to the `http.proxy` entry as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```
"http.proxy": "http://frustratedusername:password@pesky.proxy.com:8080/"
```

But it didn't work. Then, I tried setting the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables, but it didn't work neither.

Is there any way to make VS Code remember the proxy settings?

Comment: Does your username consist of domain and user name: `domain\username`?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and its frustating to input it everytime. why still no solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Tried with this install nodejs package.
then open command prompt and enter npm commands.
set the proxy using below commands

`npm set proxy http://name:password@gtpproxy.proxy.com:8080`

`npm set https-proxy http://name:password@gtpproxy.proxy.com:8080`

`npm config set strict-ssl false -g`

Note:

- Replace name with email
- Replace password with the actual password
- Replace gtpproxy with the proxy address of the location.

Answer (score 1):

Remembering proxy credential should now be supported, since VSCode 1.51 (Oct. 2020), and confirmed with [VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/8ddd24791f80161c260cb598803320428b7ce2f0/release-notes/v1_52.md#new-proxy-login-dialog-enabled-by-default)

> ### Remember proxy credentials#

> We are overhauling the login dialog that shows when a network connection requires authentication with a proxy.
> A new setting, **`window.enableExperimentalProxyLoginDialog: true`**, will enable this new experience that we plan to make the default in a future release.
>
> [image: Proxy Login -- https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_51/proxy-login.png]
> <sup>Theme: GitHub Light</sup>
>
> The dialog will appear inside the VS Code window and offer a way to remember the credentials so that you do not have to provide them each time you start VS Code.
> **Credentials will be stored in the OS standard credential store (keychain on macOS, Windows Credential Manager on Windows, and gnome keyring on Linux).**
>
> We still only show this dialog once per session, but might revisit this decision in the future. You will see the dialog appear again in case the credentials you selected to be remembered are not valid. Providing them again allows you to change them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with proxy switch in the command itself.

Something like this and it worked for me:
`node-gyp configure --proxy=http://proxy.server.name:port`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to URL-encode your username and/or password. For example, if your username contains a domain, like e.g. `DOMAIN\username`, you'll have to URL-encode the backslash. Thus, you need to use `DOMAIN%5Cusername`. The same goes for your password, URL-encode each and every non-ascii character.